# What can be causing this Firebug error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have this code:

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  function cargar(url){
    var iframe = $('<iframe>');
    iframe.attr('src', url);
    $('#screen').html(iframe);
  }   
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      cargar($(this).attr('href'));
      $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 
    $('ul li a').first().click();
  }); 
</script>
```

That generates an iframe (containing a panorama viewer with JavaScript and Flash) and inserts it in a div.

The thing is that this code, in local, Firebug jumps:

```
Elemento referenciado por ID/NAME en el ámbito global. Use el estándar del W3C document.getElementById() en su lugar.
```

google tranlated

```
Element referenced by ID / NAME in global scope. Use the W3C standard document.getElementById () instead.
```

And online it doesn't jump any error or warning but the script doesn't fully work: http://toniweb.us/m/panorama/panorama.html (the controls are missing and the autoplay is not ON)

The thing is that i don't know how to show you guys the local versión, so i just provide a .zip in case anyone is willing to have a look: http://toniweb.us/m/panorama/panorama.zip

I would really apreciate any thoughts about this, i am running out of ideas and I should had done this long a go.. :(

Comment: can you post the error in english?

Comment: Just did it (google translated)

Comment: Possibly its whining about the iframe variable having a name that matches that of an element? Try renaming it

Comment: Where yo uare getting an error i just downloaded the zip file and checked am not getting any errors in firebug?

Comment: just tried that. the thing is that online firebug doesn't jump any error..

Comment: yes may be that is the case am not facing any issue in my machine.

Comment: I doubt that that script is causing the error. Maybe its something that's loaded into the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Also when I visit the site I do not get any such errors in Firebug. It seems to work fine.

Comment: you can see the error when clicking in the navigation links on the right @Matrix thanks for checking. The thing is that i have no clue how those script work... that why i am iframing them in the first place...
what should i try?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I've loaded the site and clicked on all the links, in Firefox, with the Firebug console open, and I never see the error.

Comment: FF 9.0/Firebug 1.9.1 I do not see that error either

Comment: So what can be causing this different behavior? Because you do see the difference against the onilne version, right? @Pointy

Comment: Well what that error means is that some JavaScript somewhere is trying to reference a DOM element as if its "id" value were a global variable. I don't see that in any of the JavaScript code I could see, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Since I cannot *see* the error myself, I'm not sure I can help much.

Answer (score 1):

`Element referenced by ID / NAME in global scope` This message is related to the references to the DOM elements which are made (in your case) as `ptviewer` instead of `document.getElementById('ptviewer')`, These calls are made from the Java applet (read about interaction between Java and Javascript).

But all that you need to do in order to get rid of these messages (I decompiled the ptviewer.class) is to open `ptdefault.html` file and replace one string

```
{inits=javascript:loaded = true,ptviewer.startAutoPan(0.3,0,1) }
```

with

```
{inits=javascript:loaded = true,document.getElementById('ptviewer').startAutoPan(0.3,0,1) }
```

Comment: hey! thanks a lot! So shall i change only that ocurrence or each one?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet  Do you have other problems with the same message? Technically it looks like this is the only one place.

Comment: I don't get the same errror, but when i upload the files i don't see it the same way... please, comparte those files you downloaded (just the movement of the image is enought) with those: http://toniweb.us/m/panorama/panorama.html

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet  Please mention the nickname in response - did not see your message. You were talking about the buttons?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The weird thing is that, as I can see from the Java code, by default the toolbar should not be shown. Try to add the string `{showToolbar=true}` to the `ptdefault.html` - it reads this option from it: `if((s1 = myGetParameter(s, "showToolbar")) != null && s1.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) 
            showToolbar = true;`

Comment: @Cherry yes i ment the buttons; i tried to add the {showToolbar=true} but it didn't help... you think that might need a different parameter aswell?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet  It is difficult to tell right now, because I've tried it on my server and it works, showing the toolbar. Actually, I just looked in the logs of requests and I think I know what the problem is. Java is looking for `PTDefault.html` instead of `ptdefault.html`. So, if your server and/or file system on server is case-sensitive you have to rename the file correspondingly.